# Check if an element is present in a bag?

Tags: apache-pig

How can I check in [piglatin](/questions/tagged/piglatin), if a bag contains an element?

Example : In a bag of chararray, how can I check if a token is present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Apache Pig you can use statements nested in FOREACH [see Pig Basics](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#foreach). Here is example from the documentation:
`A` is a bag in `B`.

```
X = FOREACH B {
        S = FILTER A BY 'xyz';
        GENERATE COUNT (S.$0);
}
```

Instead of COUNT you can use IsEmpty and ?: operator

```
X = FOREACH B {
        S = FILTER A BY 'xyz';
        GENERATE (IsEmpty(S.$0)) ? 'xyz NOT PRESENT' : 'xyz PRESENT') as present, B;
}
```

Or only to leave the bags that contain the data:

```
X = FOREACH B {
        S = FILTER A BY 'xyz';
        GENERATE B, S;
}
F = FILTER X BY not IsEmpty(S);
R = FOREACH F GENERATE B;
```

This will avoid costly join to itself, as extra joins are extra Map Reduce jobs.

Comment: In PIG 0.15 you can't project B from nested expression. This did not work for me:
X = FOREACH B {
        S = FILTER A BY 'xyz';
        GENERATE B, S;
}