# How do I find intersection of a bag and an element without UDF in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have say two Pig variables,
**p** which is `(id: int, companies: tuple(name:chararray))`
and
**q** which is `(id: int, company: chararray)`.

Now after I join **p** and **q** by their "id"'s, how do I filter out those rows where `q::company` is not present in `p::companies`?

PS I went through this question [Check if an element is present in a bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390220/check-if-an-element-is-present-in-a-bag) but it seems to be not exactly as my problem.

**Example**

sample **p**

> 1,(c1 c2 c3)
>
> 2,(c4 c5 c6)
>
> 3,(c2 c3 c5)

sample **q**

> 1,c3
>
> 2,c8
>
> 3,c5

expected output after the joins

> 1,c3
>
> 3,c5

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert `p` so that every combination of ID and company name appears on its own line.

```
p_flattened = FOREACH p GENERATE 
    id, 
    FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(companies.name, ' ')) AS company;
dump p_flattened;
(1,c1)
(1,c2)
(1,c3)
(2,c4)
(2,c5)
(2,c6)
(3,c2)
(3,c3)
(3,c5)
```

Then join with q to return only IDs and names which appear in both relations and do `foreach` to get rid of the duplicate fields.

```
pq_joined = JOIN p_flattened BY (id, company), q BY (id, company);
final = FOREACH pq_joined GENERATE 
    q::id AS id, 
    q::company AS company;

dump final;
(1,c3)
(3,c5)
```